# Which email to use in Google Service Account API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Following this Google Tutorial : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

And using this PHP library : 
https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP

I have a little problem. I just don't find the email to use as described in the tutorial. I think the API interface has changed, and the tutorial is old.

I have created my project, activate Analytics API, and create a "Service account". It generates an email, but not in projectId-uniqueId@developer.gserviceaccount.com format.

I tried with the new email created (like name@name-1162.iam.gserviceaccount.com) but I catch this error :

```
invalid_grant
```

Is something changed ? What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

On the page you linked there is a basic setup:

https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP

First step is,

> Create a Project in the Google APIs Console:
>   https://code.google.com/apis/console/

And that differs completely from the other guide you have.
At best follow what it says on the github page.

Comment: In fact, you have 2 ways to set up the authenfication. I use the point 2.2 described in the project link.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but they way I read that page, it seems you have todo first chapter 1 - before getting to chapter 2. 
There is a also an open issue on github, which makes me believe the PHP-API should still work even if not cover everything.
Well if you got the private key and all.. sorry no idea.